# Cinnamon theme - Some apps only use Adwaita theme?

Tags: gtk, themes, gnome, archlinux, cinnamon

It's not a major issue, but it's been really bothering me. When I use apps like gnome-calculator, evince, or simple-scan, they never leave the default Adwaita theme. Is this normal or is there a way to get them to play nice with the theme I have set as default?

I'm using Cinnamon desktop on Arch Linux and have the Numix-Cinnamon theme set as default...

Thanks.

EDIT: Screenshot of the issue... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpegc.png

Comment: Can you determine if this affects all GTK+ 3 programs and not any GTK+ 2 programs?

Comment: @andlabs Not per-se. But some programs that work perfectly are AisleRiot Solitaire, Firefox, Chromium, GParted, Filezilla, LibreOffice, gnome-terminal, and QT apps. gedit, gnome-calculator, evince, simple-scan, gnome-system-monitor are all stuck with Adwaita though. Added a screenshot to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had Adwaita set as the control theme. Apparently, applications with that new-style Gnome 3 titlebar are styled fully by the control theme - not the window borders theme.

Comment: Did you also manage to get the close button on the left side for the evince and calc applications ?